# Indirectly executed dll messes up the root folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a solution that includes 2 projects.

The main one is an asp.net app.

The second, is a referenced project which includes NUnit tests.

What I try to do is run the NUnit tests through the web app.

So, through the web app, I invoke the nunit3 console-runner.exe, which runs against the referenced project dll (which gets [rightly] copied in the bin dir).

The problem is that the referenced project dll depends on some xml/txt files, and it cannot find them (so everything fails), because the root folder (System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()) gets interpreted differently.

When the dll gets executed through the web app, it sees as its root folder the "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express" dir, instead of the web app root folder.

I have not managed to get around it so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you start `nunit3-console.exe` using `Process.Start()`. If so, can't you just set the `StartupInfo.WorkingDirectory` to your web app root folder?

Comment: It worked Christian. K. Thank you man!!!